# Trying to read a text file using application.assets - gives "Unresolved reference"

Tags: android-studio, file, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and trying to read a text file in my app. I've been trying all the suggestions I can find without success. I've put a text file in assets and I've tried

```
val resultLines = application.assets.open("myLines.txt").readLines()
```

but application is shown in red with an "Unresolved reference" error. I've tried

```
val resultLines = requireContext().assets?.open("myLines.txt").toString()
```

but it crashes. Another suggestion was

```
val fileText: String = applicationContext.assets.open( fileName: "textfile.txt").bufferedReader() .use { it.readText () }
```

but applicationContext was an Unresolved reference.

All I want to do is read a text file with a few lines of text into a List.

Comment: See, for instance, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-a-file-from-assets-on-android. It may depend on Android version, I think. I think, application context is not required. Activity context is enough.

Comment: Where are you actually running this code? All of those examples access ``assets`` through a ``Context``, so they'll work inside e.g. an ``Activity`` (which ``is`` a ``Context``) but not in a random non-Context class. Generally for anything that pokes at the running environment, you need to pass in a ``Context`` to your function / class constructor, and call that from somewhere that *does* have access to one

Comment: Thanks CoolMind. I had looked at that previously but been put off by the Java code. I looked again and found tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-files-from-assets-on-android-using-kotlin which was what I wanted. That contains code for a new Project which I set up and it works. Based on that, I'm confident I'll now be able to update my project to work.

Answer (score 0):

The context is not needed. FileInputStream() receives a string path to find the document, should work as the following:

```
val asset = FileInputStream(stringAssetPath).bufferedReader()
            .use { it.readText() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on CoolMind's comment above, I found [tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-files-from-assets-on-android-using-kotlin](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-files-from-assets-on-android-using-kotlin) which was what I wanted. That contains code for a new Project which I set up and it works. (I had to modify it slightly for it to compile in a Fragment rather than Main.)

My original question about "Unresolved reference" has not got an answer that worked for me but it no longer occurs now that I have changed the code considerably, using the method in the website mentioned above.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not relevant to the question.